# Solving an equation with vector coefficients

Tags: equation-solving, tensors, algebra

I want to solve $(ct)^2 = d(t)\cdot d(t)$ for $t$, where $ d(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2 + vt + r$

Where$ a, v$, and $r$ are all 3-dimensional vectors in Cartesian coordinates.  How can I do this?

Comment: What is the variable that you want to solve for?

Comment: (ct)^2 is a constant?

Comment: t is the variable to solve for, c is the speed of light so a constant yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define the three vectors explicitly as

```
A = {a1, a2, a3};
V = {v1, v2, v3};
R = {r1, r2, r3};
```

your equation evaluates to a polynom in t of order 4

```
eq = (c t)^2 == #.# &[1/2 A t^2 + V t + R] // Collect[#, t] &
```

which you might solve using MMA    `Solve[eq, t]`

**addendum**

If you want preserve the invariant scalarproducts, the equation could be defined as follows

```
Clear[A, V, R]
(c t)^2 == {1/2 t^2, t, 1}.Outer[Dot, {A, V, R}, {A, V, R}].{1/2 t^2,t, 1}
(*c^2 t^2 ==1/2 t^2 A.R + R.R + 1/2 t^2 (1/2 t^2 A.A + R.A + t V.A) + t V.R+t (1/2 t^2 A.V + R.V + t V.V)*)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand). First, some assumptions, and your distance function:

```
$Assumptions = (a|v|r) ∈ Vectors[3];

d[t_] := 1/2 a t^2 + v t + r
```

Then, use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) on the tensor expanded equation:

```
Solve[
    TensorExpand[d[t] . d[t] == (c t)^2],
    t,
    Quartics->False
]
```

> {{t -> Root[
>       4 r.r + 8 r.v #1 + (-4 c^2 + 4 a.r + 4 v.v) #1^2 + 4 a.v #1^3 + 
>         a.a #1^4 &, 1]}, {t -> 
>      Root[4 r.r + 8 r.v #1 + (-4 c^2 + 4 a.r + 4 v.v) #1^2 + 4 a.v #1^3 + 
>         a.a #1^4 &, 2]}, {t -> 
>      Root[4 r.r + 8 r.v #1 + (-4 c^2 + 4 a.r + 4 v.v) #1^2 + 4 a.v #1^3 + 
>         a.a #1^4 &, 3]}, {t -> 
>      Root[4 r.r + 8 r.v #1 + (-4 c^2 + 4 a.r + 4 v.v) #1^2 + 4 a.v #1^3 + 
>         a.a #1^4 &, 4]}}

Without the [`Quartics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quartics) option, you get a mess of hard to understand radicals.